# get current windows user in webapp

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, authorization, windows-authentication

I am using `string appNetworkUserId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` to get the current user of my web application. It works when I'm running the machine locally. I get `domain\my name`, but when I run the app on my dev server I get `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` instead of the user who is accessing the website.

How can I get the user name of the visitor to my webapp?

I'm using .net 4.0 and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using. And this works.

```
 System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
 string[] a = Context.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
 string appNetworkUserId = Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You get `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` because that is the identity that is running IIS.  You get your own name in the development environment because the web server there is running as your logged-in user rather than as a system user.

If you use an authentication framework like the one in ASP.Net MVC, you can check

```
User.Identity.Name
```

in a controller action.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set up your web site to use NTLM or Integrated Windows Authentication.  Otherwise the remote user will not be authenticated as a windows users and you have no way of determining his user account.

See here for authentication mode discussions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825205(v=cs.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010(v=ws.10).aspx

Once that is configured you can get the current user by:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

// Obtain the authenticated user's Identity
WindowsPrincipal winPrincipal = (WindowsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;
```

Comment: To get the username it would be something like: winPrincipal.Identity.Name